# Showing that there is no nonzero bilinear map from $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_7$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

One can show that for any $m\otimes n \in \mathbb{Z}_5 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_7$, it is zero, since $\gcd(5,7)=1$. By universal property of tensor product, this implies that there is no nonzero $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear map from $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_7$ to any vector space (say $\mathbb{Z}^2$). I am wondering if we can show this without using tensor product but perhaps more elementary way?

Comment: $\Bbb Z^2$ isn't a vector space, it's a $\Bbb Z$-module, and $\gcd(5,7) = 1$, not $0$ :)

Comment: @Stahl Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

Let $F:\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_7\to A$ be any bilinear map. I claim the value of $F(x,y)$ is zero for all $x,y$. Assume that $x$ is nonzero. Then there is a unique nonzero $x'$ such that $7x'=x$. Then
$$F(x,y)=F(7x',y)=F(x',7y)=F(x',0)=0$$
as desired.

Comment: And this is exactly the computation showing that $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z\cong 0$. (+1)